BinaryFormatter exception when trying to Get non-existing preference key in SettingsProperty in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
using System.Configuration;

var provider = new LocalFileSettingsProvider();
var context = new SettingsContext();

var attributes = new SettingsAttributeDictionary();
var attr = new UserScopedSettingAttribute();
attributes.Add(attr.TypeId, attr);

var prop = new SettingsProperty(
    "Test",
    typeof(bool),
    provider,
    false,
    true,
    SettingsSerializeAs.Xml,
    attributes,
    false,
    false);

var propertyCollection = new SettingsPropertyCollection { prop };
var propertyValueCollection = provider.GetPropertyValues(context, propertyCollection);
var pv = propertyValueCollection["Test"];

try
{
     if (pv?.PropertyValue == null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Property value is null");
     }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(e);
 }

Two questions about this code here.
I am obviously trying to get a key that does not exists.
But why is it not then returning the default value? Isn't that the point of adding the default value in the SettingsProperty?
How should it be done instead?
Second question: The exception when trying to get a key that does not exist is this:
 System.NotSupportedException HResult=0x80131515 Message=BinaryFormatter serialization is obsolete and should not be used. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information. Source=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager StackTrace: at System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.Deserialize() at System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.get_PropertyValue() at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\****\source\repos\TestPreference\Program.cs:line 24

I am not using a BinaryFormatter, and I have specified SettingsSerializeAs.Xml. So why does this exception appear?

Might you please [edit] your question to share the full ToString() output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?  Thanks!
